# DNOA and MVC4 WebAPI integration with Delegation Handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dotnetopenauth

I would like to probe for recommendations in terms of integrating DNOA with MVC4 Web API. Currently DNOA resource server implementation has following two overloads, which take HttpRequestBase or HttpRequestMessageProperty as inputs, but these methods are no longer compatible with the new MVC 4 WebAPI message delegation handlers due to type incompatibility. Delegation handlers are around System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Discovers what access the client should have considering the access token in the current request.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IPrincipal GetPrincipal(HttpRequestBase httpRequestInfo = null, params string[] requiredScopes) 

    /// <summary>
    /// Discovers what access the client should have considering the access token in the current request.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IPrincipal GetPrincipal(HttpRequestMessageProperty request, Uri requestUri, params string[] requiredScopes)
```

I can get it up and running with a HTTP Module, but I would like to find out the intended DNOA use with MVC4 Web API especially with Delegation Handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/pull/194) for supporting `HttpRequestMessage` natively.  Until that's available, [this mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dotnetopenid/_azh928Sk0o/Nzqildq4yzcJ) thoroughly covers this question, including a few workarounds and a link to [a sample](https://github.com/DavidChristiansen/DotNetOpenAuth.WebAPI.40).